# How to fix error 000840 the value is not a raster dataset for Mosaic?

Tags: arcpy, mosaic, error-000840

I'm trying to to complete a batch mosaic operation in ArcMap 10.4.1 Python window. I need to run the Mosaic tool about 80 times for sets of three rasters. Basically I want the second raster to mosaic to the first raster with all of the default mosaic properties. My code to do this is pasted below, but after trying to run the code I receive the following error.

How do I fix this problem?

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 39, in <module>   File "c:\program files
(x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 13233, in Mosaic     raise e ExecuteError: 
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Dataset.
```

Code:

```
# Name: Batch mosaic
... # Description: Batch mosaic processes
...  
... # Import system modules
... import arcpy
... from arcpy import env
... from arcpy.sa import *
... import math
...  
... # Set environment settings
... env.workspace = "C:\Users\dtma224\Desktop\PhD\Paper 2\Timing\Subbasin Connectivity Flow Time"
...  
... # Check the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
...  
... arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
...  
... count = 1
...  
... # Run for each raster in the directory 
...  
... while count < 2:
...  
... # Execute times flow direction calculation
...       
...     name1 = "Day72Subbasin" + str(count) + " Bin 1.tif" 
...      
...     Bin1 = Raster(name1)
...     
...     name2 = "Day72Subbasin" + str(count) + " Bin 2.tif" 
...      
...     Bin2 = Raster(name2)
...     
...         
...     arcpy.Mosaic_management(Bin2, Bin1, "LAST", "FIRST", "", "","NONE", "0", "NONE")
...    
...     count = count + 1 
...
```

Comment: The presence of spaces in folder names can generate issues; spaces in table names are extremely problematic. A raster dataset is a file geodatabase table, and therefore has all the naming restrictions of any table.

Answer (score 2):

I looked for a solution to this problem and saw that it was asked here 2 years ago and has not been solved. I may have found a workaround:

I tried mosaic in ArcGIS Pro 2.7 and every time I got the same error ("`is not a raster`") when I specified a target raster. I tried creating a new raster, tried copying an existing raster, but nothing worked.

The one thing that worked, which makes me think that this is a bug, is to add `.tif` to the target raster, and then the error changes to "`raster does not exist`". But then when I remove the `.tif` the error goes away and the mosaic works as expected. I know how weird this sounds, but just in case folks are still looking to solve this annoying issue.

Comment: Thank you for this tip! In my situation it was Ortho Mapping and selecting a _Taget Raster_ from the drop down list that failed. If I use the chooser dialog and navigate to the target raster instead then it works. The path in the field changes from `My raster name` to `X:\path\to\folder.gdb\my_raster` so I surmise that the tools need a fully qualifed path name to work. Or quoted path as per @Vince's comment above.